# How access WebSession in WebFlux services?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-session

I'm using spring-webflux, And I want to use [WebSession](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/websession.html) in some different classes for one request. For example: Application has some analyze service. Clients want to run some of them. They send a request and then in controller we run something like the following:

```
classService1.analyze()
classService2.analyze()
classService3.analyze()
```

Now, In Class Services, they may need some WebSession information(such as client Ip, client session attributes and .etc). There is no way except below example to do this?

```
@RestController
class AnalyzeController() {

   @Autowired
   private ClassService1 classService1

   // Other injected class services

   @PostMapping("/analyze")
   public void analyze(WebSession webSession){
      classService1.analyze(webSession)
      classService2.analyze(webSession)
      // ...
   }
}
```

I don't want to get webSession form controller and then send it to all my services, I want a possibility to inject WebSession in my services(like `@Autowired WebSession webSession`), Or I want to use WebSession in AOP. Is it possible? If yes, How? If not, What's best way to send WebSession to services?

Answer (score 0):

The https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#websession documentation provides support for WebSession with Redis , but  if you don’t want the overhead of maintaining a Redis cluster. You can use In-Memory Session Clustering With Hazelcast.

Configure spring session to use the Hazelcast map
Make sure you add @EnableSpringWebSession.
Create a ReactiveSessionRepository bean which wraps the Hazelcast instance’s map.

```
@EnableSpringWebSession
public class SessionConfig {

    @Autowired
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    @Bean
    public ReactiveSessionRepository reactiveSessionRepository() {
        final IMap<String, Session> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap(MAP_CONFIG_NAME);
        return new ReactiveMapSessionRepository(map);
    }
}
```

And Create a Config bean as Spring Boot uses it to auto configure a Hazelcast instance 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-hazelcast.html

Comment: I am sorry I have to downvote this, because it suffers from two **major** issues: 1. it does not remove expired sessions from the map, so you have a memory leak and 2. `IMap`’s `get()` method may trigger a `load()`, which is a blocking call and should thus never happen in a WebFlux application. Unfortunately there won’t a proper solution with Hazelcast until [spring-session#831](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/831) is implemented…